# find max elements of an array in JS, elements might be same

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of questions about how to get max from an array, but they all have unique elements. my scenario is different, for example:

> find_multiple_max([10,20,30,30])

will return

> [30, 30]

I found a solution and it works:

```
function find_multiple_max(arr) {
    var max;
    arr = arr.sort((a,b) => b-a)
            .filter(e => {
                if (!max) {
                    max = e;
                    return true;
                } 
                return (e == max);
            });
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

I was still wondering if any simpler answer exists.

Comment: Can you provide your attempt at solving this yourself and highlight specifically what you're getting stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `Math.max` which will return the maximum element from the array and then use `filter` to get an array

```js
function find_multiple_max(arr) {
  let maxElem = Math.max(...arr);
  return arr.filter(item => item == maxElem)
}
console.log(find_multiple_max([10, 20, 30, 30]))
```